# working example of using stored procedures with play 1.2+

Tags: mysql, playframework

I experiencing issues using stored procedures in MySQL 5+ with Play framework 1.2.3. 
I am guessing my approach is incorrect - I am using callable statement and passing in the parameters to the stored procedure.  The procedure is not supposed to return any output variables (just being used for insertion).  Barring switching over to any ORM option, how best can I troubleshoot this setup.

```
// con is connection to mysql
CallableStatement cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call sp_InsertTest(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
cs.setString(1, user.value1);
cs.setString(2, user.value2);
cs.setString(3, user.value3);
cs.setString(4, user.value4);
cs.setString(5, user.value5);
cs.setString(6, user.value6);

//all values are strings
```

when I run the executeUpdate on the callable stmt, it throws an error from the first line mentioned above (I removed the line from the logs below from where it is being thrown):

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:220)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace is not complete so it is difficult to see exactly what error you have.

In my case stored procedure work well. You have first to get the connection with

```
Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
```

Then you can do the call. I don't put brackets in my call

```
con.prepareCall("call sp_InsertTest(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: thank you for responding - I've tried the same - the lines I removed were pointing to the line (first line in the code above) from where the exception was being thrown.  I am also looking into using play.DB.execute with a stored procedure and will update once I am done.

Comment: I am using play.db.execute and I am able to call the stored procedure from there.